# Exercises for pronouncing the r

Tags: pronunciation

I'm a dutch programmer working in a international team where English is the main language. In my native language I have pretty decent articulation. However, when speaking English I have a lot of trouble using words containing a 'r'. Most of the time I create a 'w' sound instead of pronouncing the 'r'. So words like rabbit will sound like 'wabbit', which makes me feel like I am narrating Tweety in his latest cartoon.

Are the any exercises I can do for better pronouncement of words with a 'r'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Decide which English you want to speak. Pronunciation is not the same everywhere in the English-speaking world.

Comment: It is a bit strange that you, as a Dutchman, should have trouble pronouncing [ɹ], since—as far as I know—the vast majority of Dutch people have this sound natively: it is the r sound found in, for instance, _woord_, _Antwerpen_, and in most other cases where you have r + consonant.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet:  The standard accent in the West, yes; the majority, possibly; the vast majority, I would say no. Oh, and ɹ in the coda is indeed in the standard/Western accent; but no accent has it in the onset, so that could add to P. de Raaij's issue.

Comment: I advise against listening to Jonathan Ross for rhotic tips.

Comment: @Cerb, I thought Leiden had it everywhere? At least I seemed to hear that quite a lot when I was there. I don't think I've ever heard (read: noticed) a Dutch speaker who didn't at least have it in coda before a dental; but then I may just not have heard mostly speakers from the Western areas (plus one from Groningen at least).

Comment: I have done some additional reading and Leiden is known for pronouncing the 'r' like the English 'r'. Thanks for your comments. I didn't realized there are so many forms of pronouncing the 'r' even in the Netherlands..

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Ah, yes, you're right! I forgot about the Leidse ɹ, which is indeed just like the English ɹ in both onset and coda. It is limited to lower-class Leienaren, and I can't think of any other accent with that ɹ, so you were in luck. The standard/Western accent (ABN) has ɹ in the coda, as you say, though it does sound softer or less "pronounced" than the Leidse/American codal ɹ. If you were in the West and/or mostly hung out with educated people, it makes sense that the vast majority had it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Listening to ɻ and ɹ again, I'm having trouble hearing the difference. Going by the description, ɻ should be retroflex but not ɹ; then ɹ should be standard Dutch, ɻ English/Leids? The sound in standard Dutch is barely or not at all retroflex, whereas the sound in English/Leids is at least somewhat retroflex when I do it. But Wikipedia says ɻ does not occur in any standard English accent, and I normally see the English r rendered as ɹ. So I am a bit confused: does ɻ indicate a strong retroflexion, and are standard-Dutch and Leids/English just two variants of ɹ?

Comment: @Cerb: Yes, [ɻ] is very retroflex, while the other is either not retroflex at all (as in Faeroese), or only slightly retroflex (as in Dutch or most BrE dialects). AmE dialects in general have [ɻ] (normally labialised), though it is often just rendered [ɹ] for simplicity. The Wikipedia page for the retroflex variant does specifically mention AmE and Irish English, too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Wikipedia says "some American, Irish and West Country dialects" for "English", so I took that to mean not the standard American accent? // You say "British and Dutch", but to me the British r in, for example, *red* or *parent* is slightly retroflex, while the Dutch standard r in *daar* is not retroflex at all. When I make those two r's, something different is happening in my mouth, even though they are fairly similar. I would say the British one can only occur on the onset and the Dutch one only in the coda, by the way, so they are hard to compare in isolation, or at all.

Comment: ...  Leidse and American r in the onset, by contrast, make me do exactly the same thing with my mouth, I would say they are exactly the same.

Comment: Here you are
http://epronunciation.com/pronunciation/consonants/unit-13-r.html
Please check it out.

Comment: There's always [Ruffles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCzV4MgWkkg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The American English /r/ phoneme is rounded, so there **should** be some "W" sound.

The problem is likely insufficient retroflexion. Make sure your tonguetip is curled up and back, so that you can touch your hard palate with the **bottom** of the tonguetip. With your tongue in this position and your lips rounded, say [ə]. In practice, native English speakers don't actually touch anything with their tongue when saying /r/, but the tongue is almost there and that's the position, so you can practice it.

For further phonetics, let me recommend J. C. Catford's helpful little book *A Practical Introduction to Phonetics;* it's designed for the autodidact and is full of little phonetic experiments you can do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to take a look at the book you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You have a case of [rhotacism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotacism) and two methods to correct the issue is described [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081130103306AAGC9bE) or google **Exercising the Rhotacism in Absence of Pathology**

Comment: Note for 2016: Link-only answers are now strongly discouraged. This answer gained two upvotes in 2014, but times change.

Answer (score 0):

You would do well to talk to a speech therapist -- I have no idea what exercises there might be.  But apparently the r sound as used in most dialects of English is called the "[alveolar approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_approximant)".  If you visit the link for that, you will find that the way r is pronounced in your country's city of Leiden is the way you would probably want to pronounce it in English.